# How to change the UI at production Level

Tags: javascript, java, user-interface

I have a strange requirement. I have to set the max-width of a column of table at production level.

How can i provide the solution without release.

Solution at my side :- 
when they load the UI i can provide some exe which they can run and change the UI.
But i need some another approach.
Thanks in advance.

The product is built using the complex Jquery,JavaScript code. This is one time deployment of the **webapp** per release.

The release will contains all the files (java/javascript) as a production release package.

Comment: Please do not confuse [Javascript and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245069/4733879). JavaScript is a dynamic typed client-side scripting language running in the browser, while Java is a static typed bject-oriented programming language on the JVM -> the actual machine of the user.

Comment: If you want us to give you better advise you need to tell us some more details about your app and how the UI is built. Is it a web app or java desktop app or what? Also what is considered a "release" in your production system? To update a web app you can simply update the server date and refresh the browser to "release" the update to all clients. But since you mention a "exe" file I'm not sure.